# Scalar surface integral with prime symbol, why?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

What is the difference between $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^{r} r\, dr\, d\phi$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^{r} r'\, dr'\, d\phi?$ Why the prime symbol?

What is the geometric meaning of $r'$ (in the problem below)?

**I wondering because of this problem**:
Evaluate the scalar surface integral $\iint_S dS$ where $S: x^2+y^2=r^2$.

**Solution**: Parameterize the circle: $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$:
$$\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)=r\cos\phi{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}+r\sin\phi{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}+0{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}$$ 
Where $r\in[-r,r]$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$.
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial r}=\cos\phi{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}+\sin\phi{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}+0{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial \phi} =-r\sin\phi{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}+r\cos\phi{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}+0{\mathbf{\hat{x}}}
$$
$$
\bigg \lvert \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial \phi} \bigg \rvert = r
$$
And
$$
dS=\bigg \lvert \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}(r,\phi)}{\partial \phi} \bigg \rvert \, dr \, d\phi = r\, dr\, d\phi
$$
So 
$$
\iint_S dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^{r} r\, dr\, d\phi \tag{1}
$$
However, the integral in my book is denoted
$$
\iint_S dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^{r} r'\, dr'\, d\phi \tag{2}
$$
What is the difference? The radius is $r$, but what is the geometric meaning of $r'$?

**EDIT: Follow-up question**:

From the answers $r'$ is just to distinguish the dummy/integration variable from the bounds. However, in the parameterization $r$ is the radius of the circle, but instead using $r'$ we have
$$x=r'\cos\phi \quad \text{and} \quad y=r'\sin\phi$$
But then $r'^2=r^2$?

I don't grasp it, how to think about it?

Comment: I think its $r'$ just to destinguish from the bounds of the integral.

Comment: The primed coordinates are dummy integration variables while the unprimed ones are fixed parameters not implicated in the integration process.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks! I posted a follow-up question for this in my post.

Comment: Your $S: \ x^2+y^2=1$ is a curve in the $(x,y)$-plane (with zero area), or an infinite cylinder in $3$-space, hence has infinite area.

Comment: Here $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, so they didn't (although they could have) write $d\phi'$.

Answer (score 1):

It is thought that using $r$ for bound and unbound variables at the same time is bad notation.  So
$$
\int_{-r}^r r\;dr
$$
should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! I posted a follow-up question based on this in my post.